# Cloudformation how to reference Managed-Policy from another stack

Tags: amazon-iam, aws-cloudformation

I have the following role. From within it I want to use an existing managed policy from another stack.

How can I do so?

```
"TestRole": {
    "Properties": {
      "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
        "Statement": [
          {
            "Action": [
              "sts:AssumeRole"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
              "Service": [
                "lambda.amazonaws.com"
              ]
            }
          }
        ],
        "Version": "2012-10-17"
      },
      "Path": "/lambda/",
      "Policies": [
        ??????
      ]
    },
    "Type": "AWS::IAM::Role"
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's now a supported way to do this, using [Imports/Exports](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-stack-exports.html).  Basically, the stack that creates the policy has an output that contains the policy name (or ARN, not sure which is needed in this case), and declares it as an export with a regionally-unique name.  Then, other stacks can consume it using the Import function.

For example, if the following stack (let's say it's named FooStack) creates the managed policy, it can have the following in its output:

```
"Outputs" : {
    "MyManagedPolicy" : {
        "Value" : { "Ref" : "MyManagedPolicy" },
        "Export" : { "Name" : {"Fn::Sub": "${AWS::StackName}-MyManagedPolicy" }}
    }
}
```

The other stack can use it:

```
"Policies": [
    { "Fn::ImportValue" : "FooStack-MyManagedPolicy" }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

If your requirement is  a stand-alone sharable policy. then you need to make it as `ManagedPolicy` and not a standard `Policy`.

An Example:

## 1

```
MyManagedPolicy:
Type: AWS::IAM::ManagedPolicy
Properties:
  Path: "/"
  PolicyDocument:
    Version: "2012-10-17"
    Statement:
      - Effect: "Allow"
        Action:
          - "s3:*"
        Resource:
          - Fn::GetAtt: MyBucket.Arn
```

## 2

Export it:

```
MyManagedPolicy:
Description: MyManagedPolicy
Value:
  Ref: MyManagedPolicy
Export:
  Name:
    Fn::Join:
      - "-"
      - - "MyManagedPolicy"
        - Ref: StackName
```

Then in your other stack where you want to import this stand-alone managed policy in one of your roles, do this:

```
MyUserRole:
Type: "AWS::IAM::Role"
Properties:
  RoleName: "SomeName"
  AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
    Version: "2012-10-17"
    Statement:
      - Effect: "Allow"
        Principal:
          AWS: 
            - .....
        Action:
          - .....  
  Path: "/"
  ManagedPolicyArns:
    - Fn::ImportValue:
        Fn::Sub: "MyManagedPolicy-${StackName}"
  Policies:
    - PolicyName: "NameOfYouInlinePolicyWithoutSpaces"
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Effect: "Allow"
            Action:
              - .....
            Resource:
              - .....
```

Answer (score -1):

According to the [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-ref.html) of the **`Ref`** CF function, you should be able to use that to retrieve the Managed Policy resource through its logical name.

For example:

```
Policies: [
  { "Ref" : "MyManagedPolicy" }
]
```

where "**MyManagedPolicy**" would be the name of the resource you defined in your CF template:

```
"MyManagedPolicy" : {
  "Type": "AWS::IAM::ManagedPolicy",
  "Properties": {
    "Description" : String,
    "Groups" : [ String, ... ],
    "Path" : String,
    "PolicyDocument" : JSON object,
    "Roles" : [ String, ... ],
    "Users" : [ String, ... ]
  }
}
```

Hope this helps?

Comment: You are right if it would be inside my stack, but I wanted to refer to a policy from another stack.